# ambiguous use of registerclass with Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm getting an error of "`ambiguous use of registerclass`" when doing

```
tableView.RegisterClass( cellClass: CustomTableViewCell.self,
                         forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell"
                         )
```

`CustomTableViewCell` is an Objective-c class and it's been included in a bridging header.

I couldn't figure out what's wrong with it? Can anyone tell me what does that error mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your call to `registerClass` has a parameter name (cellClass) for the first parameter. In Swift, the first parameter name is omitted.

```
tableView.registerClass(CustomTableViewCell.self, 
                        forCellReuseIdentifier: "CustomCell")
```

The reason the error says ambiguous use of registerClass is because the compiler can't tell which one you are trying to call. There are two `registerClass` methods on UITableView:

```
func registerClass(cellClass: AnyClass, forCellReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
func registerClass(aClass: AnyClass, forHeaderFooterViewReuseIdentifier identifier: String)
```

Your call doesn't match either of these, therefore it's ambiguous.

Comment: I will give it a go tonight by removing it. But how does having the first param name relate to the "ambiguous use" error?

Comment: I see. By removing param name makes it match the first call. Awesome:) Really appreciate mate. should get you a beer.